# Google Game Services connection error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have a very strange problem with Google Game Services in my Unity app for Android. I'm using 
[this library](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)
After establishing connection to the room I begin to send messages (just 1 byte) to all players in the room. After a few seconds I got exception: *Unable to communicate with RAS*
Here you can see the log: ([the same thing on github gist](https://gist.github.com/vitvakatu/f09041423995b9059ffdb51d574594ef))

```
05-29 12:05:42.824 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288): Unable to communicate with RAS
05-29 12:05:42.824 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288): android.os.RemoteException: RoomAndroidService has died
05-29 12:05:42.824 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.RoomClientState.getRemoteException(RoomClientState.java:51)
05-29 12:05:42.824 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.WaitServiceSetupState$1.binderDied(WaitServiceSetupState.java:44)
05-29 12:05:42.824 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:551)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288): Unable to kill RAS (may already be dead)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IRoomService$Stub$Proxy.kill(IRoomService.java:388)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.RoomServiceClientStateMachine.handleRasFailure(RoomServiceClientStateMachine.java:111)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.RoomClientState.handleRasFailure(RoomClientState.java:45)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.WaitServiceSetupState$1.binderDied(WaitServiceSetupState.java:44)
05-29 12:05:42.836 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:551)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288): Unable to communicate with RAS
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288): android.os.RemoteException: Service disconnected
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.RoomClientState.getRemoteException(RoomClientState.java:51)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.UnboundState$RoomAndroidServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected(UnboundState.java:79)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1219)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1233)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
05-29 12:05:42.847 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288): Unable to kill RAS (may already be dead)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IRoomService$Stub$Proxy.kill(IRoomService.java:388)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.RoomServiceClientStateMachine.handleRasFailure(RoomServiceClientStateMachine.java:111)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.UnboundState$RoomAndroidServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected(UnboundState.java:79)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1219)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1233)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
05-29 12:05:42.848 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288): Unable to communicate with RAS
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IRoomService$Stub$Proxy.leaveRoom(IRoomService.java:293)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.InRoomState.generateLeaveOnBehalfOfClient(InRoomState.java:597)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.InRoomState.processMessage(InRoomState.java:338)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.TypeSafeTransitionState$1.processMessage(TypeSafeTransitionState.java:61)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.state.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:1188)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.state.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:988)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
05-29 12:05:42.848 E/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288): Unable to kill RAS (may already be dead)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IRoomService$Stub$Proxy.kill(IRoomService.java:388)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.RoomServiceClientStateMachine.handleRasFailure(RoomServiceClientStateMachine.java:111)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.RoomClientState.handleRasFailure(RoomClientState.java:45)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.InRoomState.generateLeaveOnBehalfOfClient(InRoomState.java:599)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.roomclient.InRoomState.processMessage(InRoomState.java:338)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.statemachine.TypeSafeTransitionState$1.processMessage(TypeSafeTransitionState.java:61)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.state.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:1188)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.state.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:988)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
05-29 12:05:42.849 I/RSCStateMachine( 2288):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: What is `RoomAndroidService ` ?

Comment: @SomeshKumar actually, I don't know. There is no class with that name neither in my code, nor in code of Unity google play games plugin.

Comment: Can you provide the code around where this exception is occurring?

Comment: Does it happen all the time?  Which version of Android and Google Play Services are you running on the device?  Can you reproduce it on more  than one device?  Does the message get received?